# Invalid parameter loss for estimator Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to implement a SGDClassifier with sklearn, but I'm getting this error:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter loss for estimator Pipeline. Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

This is my code:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
 ('clf', SGDClassifier())
])

parameters = {
    'seed': [0],
    'loss': ('log', 'hinge'),
    'penalty': ['l1', 'l2', 'elasticnet'],
    'alpha': [0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001, 0.000001]
}

score_func = make_scorer(metrics.f1_score)

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=3,
verbose=1, scoring=score_func)

grid_search.fit(X, Y)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [User's Guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html#pipeline):

> Parameters of the estimators in the pipeline can be accessed using the <estimator>__<parameter> syntax

So try this:

```
parameters = {
    'clf__seed': [0],
    'clf__loss': ('log', 'hinge'),
    'clf__penalty': ['l1', 'l2', 'elasticnet'],
    'clf__alpha': [0.001, 0.0001, 0.00001, 0.000001]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> This displays exact keys to be used to reference parameters within the pipeline

```
pipeline.get_params().keys()
```