# Unable to see results from RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, grid-search

I'm making an example using pipeline for a classification problem. My issue is that I'm not able to see the results from `RandomizedSearchCV` from `scikit-learn` in `python`.

I have previously used `GridSearchCV` with these parameters(estimator,param_grid,scoring,cv) and I was able to see the optimal hyperparameters combination. My `scikit-learn` version is 0.20.0

```
import sklearn
print('The scikit-learn version is {}.'.format(sklearn.__version__))

X, y = make_classification(n_classes=2, class_sep=0, weights=[0.05,0.95],n_clusters_per_class=2,
                           n_features=2,  n_samples=10000, n_informative=2, n_redundant=0, n_repeated=0)

#Repeated ENN
renn = RepeatedEditedNearestNeighbours( n_neighbors = 5, n_jobs= 2, max_iter = 100)
#Oversampling after have undersampled
smote_enn = SMOTEENN()
#Classifier
classifier = LogisticRegression(random_state = 0)

# Make the splits
n = 2
kf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits = n, random_state = 0)

# Create regularization penalty space
penalty = ['l1', 'l2']

# Create regularization hyperparameter space
C = np.logspace(0, 4, 10)

# Create hyperparameter options
parameters = dict(C=C, penalty=penalty)

random_search = RandomizedSearchCV(pipeline, param_distributions=parameters,  n_iter=1000,  cv = kf, return_train_score = True)


 gg = random_search.fit(X, y)

 gg .best_estimator_

random_search.cv_results_
```

---

I'm getting this error

> ValueError: Invalid parameter penalty for estimator Pipeline(memory=None,
>      steps=[('logisticregression', LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, >dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
>            intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='warn',
>            n_jobs=None, penalty='l2', random_state=0, solver='warn',
>            tol=0.0001, verbose=0, warm_start=False))]). Check the list of >available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()

How I have to write the parameters?
How can I see the results from the grid search for the optimal parameters ?

Comment: '>' before 'dual' parameter.

Comment: Can you remove the parameter 'memory' and run it again?

Comment: Sorry where I have to add this > in the code ?

Comment: Can you provide, how your 'pipeline' initialization looks like?

Comment: pipeline = make_pipeline( renn , smote_enn , classifier)

Comment: Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45261459/invalid-parameter-loss-for-estimator-pipeline?rq=1). It shows that you should access parameters of the LogisticRegression by the <estimator>__<parameter> syntax. Or you could use pipeline.get_params().keys() to display the names.

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48271342/invalid-parameter-clf-for-estimator-pipeline-in-sklearn?rq=1) should give you more information.

Comment: Thank you, now it works. But If I would like to use more than 1 classifier to compare through RandomizedSearchCV how can I do ? Have you some advices?

Comment: Read this code [link](https://github.com/bmurauer/pipelinehelper/blob/master/example.py) and you will see the example where multiple pipelines are used